# Как поменять шрифт кроме иконок?

Tags: css, fontawesome, web-fonts

На сайте используется несколько шрифтов, нужно установить один, к примеру `Montserrat`, кроме иконок (на сайте так же есть `inline` стили, которые имеют различные значения для `font-family`).

Если добавить это правило:

```css
body * {
    font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif !important;
}
```

то шрифт поменяет также и *FontAwesome* иконки. Как сделать чтобы поменялся шрифт только для текста, кроме иконок?

Пытался сделать так:

```css
body *:not(::before) {
    font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif !important;
}
```

но это не работает.

Comment: `html, body { font-family:Montserrat,sans-serif; }` должно вполне хватить и не надо мудрить

Comment: @borodatych, как этого хватит, если для некоторых текстов шрифт задан в инлайн-стилях, допустим плагинами? это не сработает

Comment: @word, что, если использовать селектор по типу `body :not([class*="fa-"]), body :not(.fa)`?

Comment: @word, в исходниках не было про inline стили, предположил, ну малоли, ни с веба пришли

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте селектор, который позволит не применять правило к элементам, в которых объявлен либо класс `.fa`, либо предполагаемо содержится какой-либо класс, содержащий `fa-`

Однако будьте осторожны: к примеру, класс `.2fa-input` будет соответствовать селектору `[class*="fa-"]`).

```css
/* для тех элементов, у которых не объявлен класс `.fa`,
   но объявлен какой-нибудь другой: к примеру, .fa-camera-retro */
body :not(.fa):not([class*="fa-"]) {
    font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif !important;
}
```

**Изменено:** `font-awesome.css` содержит класс `.fa`, в котором определяется шрифт. Без него остальные классы, связанные с иконками, не имеют смысла, поэтому селектор можно сократить.

```css
body :not(.fa) {
    font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif !important;
}
```

Comment: Можно `[class^="fa-"]`.

Comment: @Qwertiy, увы, такой селектор не захватит элементы, у которых в начале атрибута класса стоит что-то иное, нежели `fa-`. К примеру, если в классе у элемента стоит `form-info fa-info`, то правило не применится.

Comment: А в каком случае на иконке может понадобиться ставить ещё классы?

Comment: Хм.. Вроде там вообще у всех иконок должен быть общий класс.

Comment: А ещё, у тебя селектор неправильный. Надо не `body :not([class*="fa-"]),
body :not(.fa)`, а `body :not([class*="fa-"]):not(.fa)`.

Comment: Насчёт `.fa`: да, действительно, посмотрел `font-awesome.css`, там и в правду этот класс определяет шрифт.